# Firebase Database Authentication Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I implemented the log-in and registration views for the Authentication via Firebase. Then how can I authenticate to my database? I changed the rules and I put:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also wrote the code for obtain the User UID, but how can I say to my database that I'm authenticated?

PS: I need the example in Swift.

Comment: Should help:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start

Comment: I already checked it. The fact is, when I'm logging in, I'm receiving the UID and with this UID how can I say to my database that I can have the right permissions?

Comment: I am having a hard time understandnig your question. The rules you shared validate that a user can only write their own node. What problem are you having with the corresponding code?

Comment: Basically I want to read from my database, after that I set that rules above. But when I'm trying to do it I'm receiving the message: failed: permission_denied on console. 

For read I'm using: 
let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("utenti").observe(.value) { (snap) in .....

Comment: The question is pretty unclear, and the above comment adds to the confusion. Are you saying you want to change the rules on the fly? As in *I want to read from my database* and then *after that I set that rules above*? Why would you want to do that? Can you provide a use case and or perhaps some code that demonstrates what you're trying to do? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 5 
Just for Authentication and then use your own code for extension

```
 let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
        withVerificationID: FireBaseverficationID,
        verificationCode: "your device code")

 let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.Company.AppName")
 let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: credential)
    defaults?.set(encodedData, forKey: "firebasecredential")
```

After this in your Extension File decode this Defaults Value and use Credential for SignIn

```
let decoded = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.Company.AppName")?.object(forKey: "firebasecredential") as! Data
    let credential = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! PhoneAuthCredential

//MARK: - If user already login with credential
    let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if userid == nil{
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if error != nil {

                return
            }
            else
            {
                //MARK:- Your desire code After Login
            }
        }
    }else{
        //MARK:- Your desire code if User already Login
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following format:

**cloud firestore**

```
  service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**realtime database**

// Checks auth uid equals database node uid

// In other words, the User can only access their own data

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
       "$uid": {
         ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
         ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: The real time database, set as you said will let all the people to be able to access to the database...

Comment: There's an update that ensures the user can only access their own data. That is just a random example, if you can give me more details as to what you want your rules to be like, then I would be able to be more accurate.

Comment: Yes! I done a main view with the log in, and I want that the UID of this user will be able to access to the database. How can I do this? Because with the above rules, everyone can read and write.

Comment: see the updated code, that ensures a certain user can access their own data and not everything

Comment: And Swift side?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly. In swift you have to write the code you want to access your database. I don't know what your app is about or what you're trying to store in your database so there's nothing I can suggest.

Comment: I’m pretty noob in database field, but for what concern... for let the authenticated user to access to my database with a specified UID, should I create a node under “users” with the UID and then Swift side how can I read what’s inside that node?

Comment: can you share a screen shot of what your realtime database looks like?

Comment: okay you are not adding any users to your database yet based on what I see. You need to create a method for registering your users. you can register your users using phone number or classic email and password and then store the registered user in your database.